# Why does $('#foo').css('width', $('#foo').css('width')) change the width?

Tags: jquery, css

One would think that after the following bit of `jQuery`, the width of the `div` selected by `#foo` would not change at all; after all, we are setting this width to the value it supposedly *already has*:

```
var original_width = $('#foo').css('width');
$('#foo').css('width', original_width);
```

In fact, this reasonable guess appears to be wrong, as shown in this [page](http://www.panix.com/~kynn/jqbug.html).  I give the code below.  The important thing to note is that the four main sections, corresponding to the four `.level-0` `div`s, all have the same structure and content.  The second and fourth of them (which have the `jqbug` class) have their width "re-set" (with a bit of JS, as described above) to the value it supposedly already has.  For the second one case, the width is actually changed by this operation; for the fourth case, the width remains unchanged, as expected.  The only difference between the definitions of the second and fourth cases is that the former has `border-box` for its `box-sizing` parameter.

```
<div class="level-0 border-box">
    <div id="i1" class="level-1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="level-0 border-box">
    <div class="level-1 jqbug">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="level-0">
    <div id="i1" class="level-1">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="level-0">
    <div class="level-1 jqbug">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

```
  (function ($) {
    $('.jqbug').each(function () {
      $(this).css('width', $(this).css('width'));
    });

  }(jQuery));
```

```
*{
  outline:3px solid green;
}

.border-box, .border-box *{
  -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
          box-sizing:border-box;
}

.level-0{
  position:relative;
  margin:10px auto;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  font-family:consolas,monaco,courier,monospace;
}
.level-1{
  position:absolute;
  padding:10px 20px;
  background-color:#0aa;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

In this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eDekJ/), which uses exactly the same code as shown above, all the `div`s end up with the same width.  On the one hand, this is good: the results have the appearance one would expect.  On the other hand, the fact that jsFiddle's result is not representative of what the browser produces directly is just as puzzling as jQuery's behavior.

My questions are:

1. Is this a bug in jQuery, or is this puzzling behavior somehow in agreement with the CSS spec?
2. What does one need to do to get the result produced by jsFiddle to look like that produced by the browser?

EDIT: I modified the JS (in both the page linked above and the jsFiddle, as well as in this post) to match that given in Marco Biscaro's answer; this made no difference to the appearance of the page as displayed directly by the browser, but it did affect the appearance of the jsFiddle's result.  Now the latter shows no difference in the widths of the various divs.  This result still differs from that produced directly by the browser, so the situation is not much better than it was before: we still have that jQuery produces surprising results, and jsFiddle produces results that do not match the browser's results.

Comment: was dying to post a "lol" but I rather be constructive.. :) 
Could it be you have a bugged up css reset?
Tried it with different browsers?
Some browsers tends to do calculated widths

Comment: You never set the widht, so jQuery tries to get it anyway, and probably uses outerWidth as it gets the width including the padding. Using `$('.jqbug').width()` gets the correct value

Comment: @adeneo Why don't you post that as an answer? Seems pretty legit to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different divs with the same class. When you do:

```
$('.jqbug').css('width')
```

The width of one of the divs is returned (I don't know exactly how jQuery determines which of two). In your hosted page, the value returned is `234px` while in jsFiddle the value is `274px` (again, I don't know exactly why). This is why the behaviour is different between the two pages.

This returned value is applied as width of both divs, but because one div has the `box-sizing: border-box` and the other hasn't, one div gets bigger than the other.

jQuery won't change the width of any div, as expected, if you set the width as the original width **and use `$(document).ready`** (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14084):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.jqbug').each(function () {
        $(this).css('width', $(this).css('width'));
    });
});
```

Comment: "jQuery won't change the width of any div, as expected": this assertion is incorrect outside of jsFiddle; I changed the code to match what you posted, and the second `div` still has its width changed.  See my EDIT above.

Comment: @kjo It works if using `$(document).ready`. It's a jQuery bug

Comment: @ MarcoBiscaro: I can't thank you enough!  Today I've been going from one nonsensical situation to another.  Your post is the first thing made sense all day...

Answer (score 0):

This problem is caused by the fact that the first div has the css class border-box on the higher level element which has a different width vs the second element where the parent element does not have border-box set on it.

border-box has the box sizing model set on it. This means it takes the width+padding.

This causes the inline width set by jquery to be overriden.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the outerWidth, it will calculate the actual width including padding and border

```
var original_width = $('#foo').outerWidth();
```